# How to translate words "Figure" and "Table" in bookdown::html_document2 documents?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

In `bookdown` projects, it is possible to translate automatically generated words, such as "Table" or "Figure" by changing settings in the `_bookdown.yml` file (see https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html). An how can I achieve the same result (translate the words) in `bookdown::html_document2` documents?
The contens of my R Markdown document:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r fig1, fig.cap=CAPTION}
CAPTION = "My plot.  "
plot(women)
```
````

And the figure caption in the rendered document is:

[image]

I'd like to have "Fig." instead of "Figure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a file *_bookdown.yml* in the same directory as your *.Rmd*. It should look like this:

**_bookdown.yml**

```yaml
language:
  label:
    fig: "Fig. "
```

**.Rmd**

````r
---
title: your doc
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

# Chapter 1

A reference to Figure \@ref(fig:women).

```{r women, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="CAPTION"}
plot(women)
```
````

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a one-document solution. Still, this answer solves my issue. Thank you.